# DataGridView: how to trigger a grid reload at the end of RowLeave handler avoiding the reentrant call exception?

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, datagridview

**Please bar any "this is bad design, etc." answers. This is just an example of a more complicated situation I am looking at.**

Let's say I have a DataGridView in a form. I have it loaded with data and I am currently in a RowLeave event delegate handling the RowLeave event. Let's say in the RowLeave event I am going to make changes to the entire DataGridView. After I am done with all the changes I would like to present the result to the user. After he clicks OK, I would like to reload the data back into the DataGridView (noting I am still in the RowLeave event handler). How would you refresh the DataGridView right after the RowLeave handler completes (or as close to) or in RowLeave handler itself avoiding the dreaded:

```
Operation is not valid because it results in a reentrant call to the SetCurrentCellAddressCore function
```

I can think of a couple of ways:

(1) setting some global variable at the end of the RowLeave handler and then having a timer look at the variable every x seconds and refresh the DataGridView.
(2) is there a way to put a message on a windows events queue that can be used later to trigger the refresh? Any sample code to do that?

There has to be a more clever and more reliable way to do this than #1... Is there a way to do #2?

Comment: do you try to change the "currentcell"-propertie? some more code may be useful ;)

Comment: I think the best idea is to just boil this question down to "how would you call a method right after an event handler is invoked BUT NOT during the execution of the event handler?"

Comment: If I'm right your problem is setting of CurrentCell-Propertie at this Event -> it would cause a endless event triggering loop so you get your error. try not to set currentcell-propertie by using row and cell ids

Comment: @DJmRek - can you provide an example as an answer?

Comment: look [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f824fbbf-9d08-4191-98d6-14903801acfc/operation-is-not-valid-because-it-results-in-a-reentrant-call-to-the-setcurrentcelladdresscore?forum=winformsdatacontrols) for my idea. I think this is similar to your problem, only other events. I think, I couldn't explain it much easier than there :)